# Loop arrays and merge to a master array while not knowing names of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, shopify

I know how to merge arrays manually, but I need to merge arrays in a loop, while not knowing the names of the arrays or how many times they will loop.

I can do this manually:

```
$masterarray = array_merge_recursive($searchcustomers1, $searchcustomers2);
```

but how do I do it in a loop. This is what I have:

$pages is how many times it needs to loop

```
 for ( $i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i += 1) {
        $searchcustomers[$i] = $sc->call.....//an API call
            }
```

How would I merge or append all the $searchcustomers[$i] to each other into a master array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you

```
$allCustomers = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i += 1) {
    $allCustomers = array_merge($allCustomers, $searchcustomers[$i]);
}
```

Comment: hmm I keep getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['  on that first line with the brackets $allCustomers = []; I think because I'm on PHP 5.3.6

Comment: I replaced [] with array() for 5.3. That doesn't give an error, but for some reason the merge seems to be duplicating the first array twice, not appending the second with the first.

Comment: this is my code now but it's replicating the first array, not appending the second with the first. I know that there are 2 arrays in this loop.

`$allCustomers = array(); 
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i += 1) {
$searchcustomers[$i] = $sc->call('GET','/admin/customers.json?limit=250&page=$i&fields=first_name,email,accepts_marketing');
  $allCustomers = array_merge($allCustomers, $searchcustomers[$i]);
    }
    echo "<pre>";
   print_r($allCustomers);
   echo "</pre>";` sorry I dont know how to format the code on here

Comment: Omg the problem with my loop was the call wasn't in double quotes so it wasn't reading the $i variable. Solved! Thank you man. You're code did help!!